# Inheriting aiml in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, aiml

I am trying to inherit aiml kernel through class approach

```
import aiml

class Kern(aiml.Kernel):
    def __init__(self):
       super(Kern, self).__init__(self)

k = Kern()
```

aiml.Kernel is a class but still I am getting the below error when I am trying to instantiate the super class from which Kern has inherited

```
super(Kern, self).__init__(self)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Please let me know what is the mistake that am making

Comment: And are you using Python 2 or Python 3? The proposed duplicate only makes sense for Python 2 if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes @tripleee python 2.7

Comment: Unless you are forced by external factors, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`super` does not accept `self` as argument. Get rid of both `self` in the line. Following shall work fine

```
super(Kern).__init__()
```